Windows DNS. Can you have the same primary zone on multiple DNS servers?
We're largely a Windows shop with AD-integrated DNS. We have a need to set up several Windows servers running the DNS service, but not the AD Directory Service.
I believe we need to set up secondary zones on the DNS servers, using the zones on the domain controllers are their primary zones. Then set the domain controllers to allow zone transfers to those servers.
My colleague states that we need to set up primary zones on the new DNS servers, then set the domain controllers to allow transfers to these servers.
It's been so long since I used Windows without AD integration that I can't remember which is the case. Can a DNS server have a primary zone that syncs with an AD-integrated zone? Can you have multiple primary zones (AD-integrated or not) syncing with one another? Or is it just one server with primary zones and the rest with secondary zones?

one to many is the correct answer which means only one goalkeeper (primar) but many players (secondary) can play the correct game, but we can't help you with learning materials, due its not on topic for serverfault.com.

I would simply use a conditional's forwarder. So if a request got asked for a name inside your domain, those DNS outside your AD will ask your AD's DNS for the entry.
My reasoning is possibly those remote computers are not inside your domain, as they would need more AD service if yes, so that way with a conditionial forwarder it will limit the access (no sync, but a cache will exist) and will make their DNS work for ressources needed for them.
A printscreen of the windows where to set it;


On domain controllers you must have or should have a back up DNS server with all same names. The answer is yes. In fact, you run as many as you want as long as the sync is offset, to say domain controllers sync together on time. Your back up should be 30 minutes behind unless the DNS is encrypted then the time must match,
which is why in real time set up you have DNS to internet, it does not contain any DNS information, only DNS to internet domain controllers all internet forwards should be removed as there no reason for domain DNS be getting data from internet. Now you should run both DNS servers on a computer on which you have access to all information, on internet and domain in event system hack there on an internet DNS server which has no data or domain set up.
There used to be a problem with DNS encryption that if you try to encrypt the reverser look up DNS would fail as a whole. I do not know if this problem was ever fixed. Another reason that you should do this more so on domain controllers is to reduce lag time more so on very complex networks. Some businesses say that Microsoft has thousands of DNS servers wins servers, and so on, mainly to offload traffic from jamming up the domain server as to point if you have two domains, and two DNS servers, that had all domain data, you only put in the second DNS server and not use DNS on any PC. Doing this prevents overloading the DNS server, but they must by kept in sync, because if you add computers it will add to the second DNS but it must be told to update the domain server as well. More so if it joins it for guest traffic this is information no one should have access to so you have DNS zone for guest networks, with a shot life span of say 30 minutes.

Hi. Your answer, as you posted it was very confusing. See my edits for what I did. In the future, please include appropriate spacing, punctuation, spelling, grammar, and make sure to make sentences readable by others.
